# Only getting city from GPS coordinates

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to only get the city name from gps coords ?

```
curl 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=43.7,7.26&sensor=false'
```

gives me several addresses, much more than I need. I did not find any filter options in the query, I would expect something like an additionnal "q=city" for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used geocoder module (for node.js) and parse the json response to get the locality.

Answer (score 1):

I found [GeoLite](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/). At least for those who need the centre location of cities using an integrated database.